# Enhance the protection of my Python source code

Tags: python, encryption, obfuscation

> Disclaimer: I know NOTHING about Cryptography, same can be said about
>   my programming skills as well ^^

After some research on how I can protect my python source code on similar topics here and other sites, most agree that I should convert my `.py` file to `.pyd` using Cython, but the problem is in the space where I'm willing to sell the code (forex trading algorithm), a lot of people make living off decompiling source codes.

I have thought of obfuscating the `pyd` file as an additional layer of security but I'm not quite sure how to do so and I still don't know if obfuscation help making the `pyd` code harder to read or the `assembly` version or both !!

I know ANYTHING can be cracked, I'm just trying to find a solution to make things a bit harder for hackers that it's no longer worth their time!

Comment: don't sell your code... just host it on your own server... provide an api or web interface or mobile UI that calls it.... sell access not code

Comment: @JoelFan I saw some posts about doing that option, the problem is that code needs to be run 24/7 and relying on my server means that I need to have a dedicated pc operating full time which I don't have right now!

Comment: Are you a time traveler from 1975?  Google cloud computing

Comment: @JoelFan I wish I was! ok, I'll do that, but is there any other way aside from doing this?

Comment: I understand your dilemma, but many people who've started down this road later regret having wasted their time on it. That said, you can play around with https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec and see what you can execute that way. Once you are comfortable with that you can then knock yourself out obfuscating the source that you will eventually provide for exec-ing.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I'm getting more confused every time I dig deep into this stuff!
from my understanding of this exec function, that it'll execute the program in form of a string! so I'm not sure if it can work, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the end-user has to have a file to upload to their trading broker terminal in order to work, which may limit the idea of making a web interface as @JoelFan proposed! , so is there a way to execute my original code on the remote server through another script distributed to buyers?!

Comment: I've never actually used it but it says it accepts a string *or* a code object. That string would consist of the entire program you want to protect, or maybe just part of it. Or you could create a code object using for example using [py_compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for the elaboration, but I'll run into the same problem which is I'd have to include in the distributed python script to the buyer a link "SSH" for example to access my server in order to execute the file on there, and they can just download its contents ?! am I right or I'm missing something here?

Comment: You were asking about obfuscation. The code you deliver would be obfuscated and thus would require some reverse engineering to retrieve. Maybe I'll post an example a little later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of code obfuscation using a few simple operations together with the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function. The obfuscated portion of code is the `fib` function. See if you can determine what it is.

```py
from base64 import b64decode

code1 = b'CbaKdTwxFl317Zq13s3agdfQZWHwXZ7JV7vVvwiwhhJNEIgbaV1HoDR54/KoeVW1UArBeEVEhWfB1iDMDrzSz6NI6oIpxDs3A4/Ai9QQxUo0g2ri26Bd9zpunDy1ZUsUOPJgz1nWMB7KMMQ7AilCSZu0Vqugu1wouuPgisoznaoNmKvaYgrPXSVPE4BNfH9af5bmva/hjS5FPJwwfkCpX4CCzg2m6H9VzbX4nnSjy8hqNYoPmiRniV5i6yLqSFJ0+shXEQ=='
code2 = b'A9LvExxXfz/dg7OP1O36ofe/CQWVL7LpONexnzWQtz5tIII7SX1nyVJZ09KURHXbcDb8WHR+j0fh9gDsLpzyvcY8n/BH5BNYb+ul+fgwqiZQqjGMhqpX1xpOvFraF2tLGJsO7yu3XnmvGPQXIkdiZLuGf5Gqm3wImsPAqupQ6Nh//cWuQjfvMkkrM6ttExM+GuTsnY/BrQ5lHLxfEiTMLayioWHCyEJ1otmcslTAvroYUOR7kARHqX4QjlafOjxUlaQzGw=='

exec(bytes(x ^ y for x, y in zip(b64decode(code1), b64decode(code2))).decode('utf-8'))
print(fib(200))
```

Now you can take this simple example and make it more and more complicated, adding encryption layers and so forth. But the bottom line is that it's not that hard to reverse engineer this and recover the source code, as long as the attacker is sufficiently motivated.

On the other hand, this makes the code harder for you maintain and debug. So it is possible to make the attacker do a little work to recover your source code, but you may decide it's not worth it.

**EDIT**: Some comments have suggested that this is a bad example because it's a concocted weak strawman which somehow puts "real" commercial obfuscators in a bad light. That was not the intent, however in my experience wearing the black hat commercial obfuscators don't really add that much. As always, it depends on your threat model. If your worried about someone who is actually getting paid to reverse engineer your code, commercial obfuscators are of minimal value for the following reasons:

1. I can buy the obfuscator myself and figure out the transformations it makes. This gives me a substantial leg up over some script kiddie.
2. It's still mostly one-time work. As software goes through revisions it typically changes very little. The reverse-engineered source that I obtained from my initial hard work will allow me to quickly recover the changes from the next revision. In other words, I get to amortize my initial efforts over many succeeding versions. I can also go backwards to previous versions just as easy.
3. Because I can do an exec within the code I am exec-ing, it's straightforward to extend this simple example to arbitrary levels of nesting. You can achieve substantially the benefit you get from expensive commercial obfuscators for free.
4. Commercial obfuscators still have all the downsides I mentioned above. Your code will have bugs, you will need to receive feedback from your users about those bugs, but now *you* have to de-obfuscate the error information you receive. And yes, the commercial products will have tools to assist you here, but even so it's just a pain in the ass. If you do pay for an obfuscation product, make sure you buy it outright with a lifetime license for the de-obfuscation tools.

If your goal is to keep honest people honest, you don't need commercial obfuscators. If your goal is to keep out a determined hacker with a modest budget from reverse engineering your code, commercial products won't be able to stop them. There may a middle ground between these two where commercial is the way to go, but I haven't found that to be the case.

Comment: thanks again for taking the time to help,
from my humble understanding, this was encoded by a base64 and decoded by exec function, then get printed
I believe this was encryption, not obfuscation!
Also, I still wander whether obfuscating the original code makes only the original code harder to read or also affects the assembly version?

Comment: In fact obfuscation by "encryption" is generally trivial to reverse engineer, because your delivered solution must contain the decryption code.   This is a bad solution.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Nonsense, obfuscation techniques are all more or less equal, all more or less useless, and all must contain the de-obfuscation code in them.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: That's not true.   Some obfuscators (ours at least) scramble the identifier names and screw up the layout.  The code does not contain anything that will unscramble those those names, nor does it contain "a formatter" (although you can probably get one of those).  Stronger obfuscators (not ours yet) scrmable the control flow structure, the data accesses and make the predicates controlling conditional branches nearly impossible to reason about yet still functionally correct.   This kind of code obfuscation can only be de-obfuscated by really difficult reverse engineering.

Comment: I cheerfully admit a "conflict of interest".   We do sell low-end obfuscators and they serve some clients needs well enough; you don't need a bank-vault style lock on the front door of your house.  Just enough to discourage most thieves.   I'll note you have your own bias which I don't believe is supported by the facts of serious obfuscators; its sure wrong IHMO in terms of believing in "encrypting" as a solution of any kind.  If you don't believe in ours (as being too weak for some purposes; fair enough) then check out Christian's Collberg's work (http://collberg.cs.arizona.edu/)

Comment: @IraBaxter: There is no possible way to read my answer as claiming "encryption" as a better obfuscation solution. It just more smoke for the show. Here is the only sentence where the words "encryption" occurs: *...adding encryption layers and so forth. But the bottom line is that it's not that hard to reverse engineer this and recover the source code, as long as the attacker is sufficiently motivated.* And as for the rest, I stand by the last paragraph of my answer.